# SMSC or SMS Gateway to store messages - java

Tags: java, sms-gateway, restcomm, mobicents, ss7

I am trying to come up with a solution for a project, I need to develop a system which can monitor all the messages sent/received by employees using company GSM connection. I am new to SS7 protocols and did some investigation on java based projects and library. First, do I need to deploy an SMSC in which can be used to send and receive messages and store in DB as well, the solution I found is Restcomm SMSC gateway? But this solution which I am working is not for Telecom operators but for small marketing organization. Another one is SMSLib but I am not sure if this can be used for this problem, as we only want to intercept the user SMS over SIGTRAN (checked with the operator we need to use this) and Restcom SMSC gateway seems to be overkill for this project. Can someone please share if even this doable or not and please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi @Jawwad, 
when you say you want to track "all the messages sent/received by employees using company GSM connection", what exactly are you referring to?

Is your company a telecom operator? Or do you just have some SIM cards that you have purchased from a Mobile Network Operator in your country, and you would somehow like to track usage of these SIM cards?

Comment: Hi. I worked in a company that deploys SMSC's for large purposes, and we were able to read all messages if needed by printing all cdr's with a message variable. Now for keeping this data not just in some log, we used ElasticSearch for saving the data in a db (ofcourse the cdr's were in json format for making things easier for ES). After doing this it was possible to track all SM messages MT and MO

Comment: thanks for the edits.